# running Java application with '-cp ...' option in Docker

Tags: java, docker, cmd

When I want to run my java program through the command line (`cmd`), I do the following:

1. Open the first `cmd` to start the server
   1.1 - `javac API.java`
   1.2 - `javac CLI.java`
   1.3 - `java -cp .;.\mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar API`
2. Open a second `cmd` for the client
   2.1 - `java CLI`

In the `Dockerfile` I wrote it like this:

```
FROM openjdk

COPY . /java

WORKDIR /java

RUN javac API.java
RUN javac CLI.java

CMD [ "java", "-cp", ".;.\mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar", "API" ]
CMD [ "java", "CLI" ]
```

The -cp option doesn't want to work.
And is it possible somehow to run `java CLI` in a new terminal?

Comment: What does "doesn't want to work" mean?   You know RUN means "run at the time you're building the docker image", not when the docker image is run, right?  And ["there can only be one CMD instruction in a dockerfile"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Java recognizes a [`CLASSPATH` environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).  You can set this environment variable using a Docker `ENV` directive, and if you do this, you don't need to worry about getting the command-line `java` options correct.

```bash
# Note Unix conventions: `:` separates elements, `/` between path components
ENV CLASSPATH .:./mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar

CMD ["java", "API"]
```

```bash
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 my-image # runs the default CMD
docker run --rm -it my-image \
  java CLI                          # runs this command instead
```

Comment: I have Windows, not Unix system